# Not able to call Service inside WebSocket listener in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

I have implemented WebSockets in Nestjs using below method and one of the requirement is that I need to update the db once I receive any message from websocket server. 
In order to do that I have done the below code but getting error like this:

But if I call the same method inside any other controller method it works fine(check /test1). Only when I call it from websocket listener I'm getting this error. Even if I call simple method from same controller to just print some log, I'm getting the same error **TypeError: this.processData is not a function**. Weird!

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong with this?

```
(node:11421) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateResponseData' of undefined
    at WebSocket.incoming (/opt/dist/controller/sample.controller.js:62:44)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/opt/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:800:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/opt/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:423:14)
    at Receiver.getData (/opt/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:353:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/opt/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:139:22)
    at Receiver._write (/opt/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:74:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
    at Socket.socketOnData (/opt/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:875:35)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)    
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
(node:11421) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11421) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Controller Code :**

```
import { Controller, Post, Get, Inject, Req, UsePipes, Body, Header,Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import * as WebSocket  from 'ws';
import { DatabaseService } from '../service/datafetch.service';

@Controller('sample')
export class SampleController {

    @Inject(dbService)
    private dbService: DatabaseService;

    static ws: any;
    static wsnew: any;
    public receiveDistData = '';

    // Connect WS & Listen to messages
    constructor() {
        this.initWs();     

        SampleController.ws.on('message', async function incoming(data) {
            console.log('message recieved 8081');
            var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
            await this.dbService.updateResponseData(dataJson);
            return data;       
        }); 
    }

    @Get('/test/data/:id')
    async testData(@Param('id') id: string) {
        return await this.callWs(id);
    }

    @Get('/test1/data/:id')
    async testData1(@Param('id') id: string) {
        const data = {id: id, data:{}};
        return await this.dbService.updateResponseData(data);
    }

    async initWs() {
        SampleController.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8081');
    }

    async processData() {
        console.log('Printing a log...');
    }

    // Data Distribution
    async callWs(id) {    
        // If Socket is not opened, try to re-open    
        if(SampleController.ws.readyState != 1) { 
            console.log('Server is dead....');
            this.initWs();
        }

        const Data = await this.dbService.findAll(id);
        await SampleController.ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            event: 'channel1',
            data: Data,
        }));
    }

}
```

**Repository Code:**

```
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { SampleRepository } from '../repository/sample.repository';

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(SampleRepository)
    private readonly sampleRepository: SampleRepository
  ) {}

  async updateResponseData(data): Promise<any> {
    return await this.sampleRepository.updateData(data);
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to make the `ws` variable static?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes. I cannot call normal variable inside constructor. That's why I changed them to static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside an anonymous function, `this` refers to the global object, not the instance of your service.

Instead you can use an arrow function. Here, `this` refers to the class instance, as you would expect:

```
async function(data) {
  // this is global object
  this.call();


(data) => {
  // this is the same as in enclosing object
  this.call();
```

Comment: I know that I'm missing something very basic and damn, this one really got me. Thanks for the help Kim!