# passing variable from config service into Typescript decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I would like to create a scheduled task for my NestJs application. It should execute every X seconds so I use intervals as described [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#declarative-intervals).

The application makes use of configuration files so I could use keep the interval configurable. But how would I pass in a variable to the Typescript decorator?

NestJs is providing a [sample repository](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/27-scheduling/src/tasks/tasks.service.ts#L13) for scheduled tasks

So based on the sample I would like to have something like

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  constructor(
    private readonly myConfigService: MyConfigService,
  ) {}

  @Interval(this.myConfigService.intervalInMilliseconds)
  handleInterval() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Do I have to use the `SchedulerRegistry` as described below in the docs? It seems this is not possible with standard Typescript, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756294/how-to-pass-an-instance-variable-into-typescript-decorator-arguments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible with the declarative API (annotations), you have to register the cron job dynamically (see [the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-intervals)):

```
@Injectable()
export class TasksService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly myConfigService: MyConfigService,
    private readonly schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry,
  ) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => this.handleInterval, this.myConfigService.intervalInMs);
    this.schedulerRegistry.addInterval('my-dynamic-interval', interval);
  }

  handleInterval() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read about the lifecycle here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-sequence and updated my code to https://hatebin.com/lnbjulqpem This seems to work fine now. But the logger instance is undefined with the new code. I tried to assign the logger within the constructor and within the `onModuleInit` function but both times it still remained undefined..

Comment: It's the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59614379/4694994 you have to use an arrow function to correctly bind `this`: `() => this.deleteExpiredTokens()`

Comment: ahhh ok. I thought I could optimize it a little bit but your approach was necessary :)